# Can't get the Navbar in a Shiny App to look properly

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

In my App I use a Navbar. I tried all the free CSS Bootstrap stylesheets from Bootswatch.com (even modified them) but I always end up like this:

[image]

The Title is "Instagram Analyzer". The first Menu Item is in the same row and the second moves one row below that. Can anyone figure out which part of the CSS code produces that "bug"?

In this picture I have used "Amelia" Style.

Here the ui.R code:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Instagram Analyzer",
               tabPanel("One User at a Glance",
                        fluidRow( column(width = 12,h1("Instagram Analyzer"))  
                        ),
                        fluidRow( column(width = 4,selectInput("user",label="Instagram User",choices=data)), 
                                  column(width = 8,tableOutput("basics"),tableOutput("z")) 
                        ),
                        fluidRow( column(width = 12,plotOutput("plot"))
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel("Manage Database"),theme="instagram.css"
))
```

And here you find the stylesheet:
http://bootswatch.com/amelia/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fluidRow` etc within the first tabPanel needs to be in a container:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = 
              navbarPage("Instagram Analyzer",
                         tabPanel("One User at a Glance",
                                  fluidPage(
                                    fluidRow( column(width = 12,h1("Instagram Analyzer"))),
                                    fluidRow( column(width = 4, selectInput("user", label="Instagram User", choices = c(LETTERS[1:4]))), 
                                              column(width = 8, tableOutput("basics"), tableOutput("z")) 
                                    ),
                                    fluidRow( column(width = 12, plotOutput("plot")))
                                  )
                         )
                         , tabPanel("Manage Database")
              )
            , server = function(input, output, session){

            })
)
```

[image]